# how to get all tasks from outlook with Microsoft Graph or Office 365 REST API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am building a web application that needs to fetch all tasks from an organization that uses Outlook Task. Can this be done with Microsoft Graph or Office 365 REST API?

I haven't found any calls in the documentation of either services that would do something similar to that: `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/tenant/tasks`

Should I find another approach or is it something that is doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Outlook Tasks](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/outlooktask) is available in Preview on Microsoft Graph today:

`GET /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/outlook/tasks` ([Graph Explorer example](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/outlook/tasks&method=GET&version=beta))

I'm afraid I don't have an ETA for when this will be generally available at the moment. According to the [Change Log](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/changelog#outlook-tasks) this functionality was added in April so it is still a somewhat recent addition.

This functionality is also available as part of the [Office 365 REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/task-rest-operations).

If you're looking for something production ready today, you may need to use this API instead. If possible, I would suggest waiting for Graph. Graph is where all future engineering energy will be focused and is the best long-term integration play.