# Microsoft Graph API - /me/tasks - Unsupported segment type?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am struggling with tasks using the Microsoft-Graph API and wonder, if the tasks (Microsoft To-Do / former Wunderlist) are already accessible in MS-Graph or is it just avaialbe via the Office365-Graph?

The task API is mentioned here:
https://todosupport.helpshift.com/a/microsoft-to-do/?s=integrations&f=does-microsoft-to-do-have-a-public-api&l=en&p=web

It points to the Office365-Graph:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/task-rest-operations

I am using the MS graph client for node.js.
The authentication seems fine. I can get information about "me". 
But unfortunately still struggling with /me/taskfolders or /me/tasks.

Help is appreciated.
Any advice? If it is not supported, yet - any plans of porting over the tasks API to MS-Graph?

I also tried '/me/outlook/tasks' which supposed to be the path in beta  API.
Still the same issue. ([how to get all tasks from outlook with Microsoft Graph or Office 365 REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150719/how-to-get-all-tasks-from-outlook-with-microsoft-graph-or-office-365-rest-api?rq=1))

Sample call:

```
client
.api('/me/TaskFolder')
.post({message: taskItem})
.then ((res) => {
 console.log(res)
}).catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
});
```

Output:

```
2018-03-09T15:02:06.449Z d3819ee2-23aa-11e8-a8c7-bd3f1fc131a9 { statusCode: 400,
code: 'BadRequest',
message: 'Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: users/myName@outlook.com/TaskFolder',
requestId: 'a829bb0c-6741-44a0-b803-34b9b5eaa901'
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for that nice hint. I guess this topic fits well here - the MS-Graph site proposes to give feedback and clarify technical questions here.

Comment: Yes you are right. That topics fits well here. What exactly does that has to do with my comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Graph Outlook Tasks are not under `/me/tasks` they are under `/me/outlook/tasks`.

More on this here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/outlooktask

Comment: Great. I was missing the "beta" tag when using the graph-api.
Nevertheless, this tasks API lacks the ability of folders / multiple list, which seems to be available via the outlook 365 API only...

Comment: There is task folders concepts in Graph just like outlook endpoint. Please read the documentation